# Having trouble passing GLInt as a reference

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, opengl-es

I have the following code:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &_defaultFramebuffer);
```

To which I'm getting the warning:

```
Passing 'GLint *' (aka 'int *') to parameter of type 'GLuint *' (aka 'unsigned int *') converts between pointers to integer types with different sign
```

How would I make that warning go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glGenFramebuffers` expects an array of unsigned ints (`GLuint *`) , but you are providing an array of signed ints (`GLint *`).

Have `_defaultFramebuffer` be of type `GLuint *` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the signature of _defaultFrameBuffer, cast it to (GLuint*) and you should be fine

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, (GLuint*)&_defaultFramebuffer);
```